# Make a full-text search with zend framework 2

Tags: php, full-text-search, zend-framework2, innodb, match-against

I have a table called 'app_curso'

Which is like this:

**TABLE**

```
CREATE TABLE `app_curso` (
  `cur_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cur_nombre` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cur_id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `cur_nombre` (`cur_nombre`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I want to make a full-text search in 'cur_nombre' field. I was trying with this part of code.

**SERVICE**

```
      $query = $_GET['q'];
      $page = $_GET['page'];

      // This is the object where I get all DB references
      global $db;

      $sql    = new Zend\Db\Sql\Sql($db);
      $select = $sql->select();
      $select->from('app_curso');

      // Here is where I want to make the search but it doesn't work
      $select->columns(array(new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression(
                             "MATCH(column) AGAINST('Query') AS curso")))
             ->where("MATCH(cur_nombre) AGAINST(".$query." in boolean mode)");


      $selectString = $sql->getSqlStringForSqlObject($select);
      $result       = $db->query($selectString, $db::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE);

      $rowset = new Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet();
      $rowset->initialize($result);

      $rows = $rowset->toArray();
```

**How can I make a full-text search using zf2?**

I think it is the right way how to make a full text search; however, I assume I'm missing something.

I have to be honest, I'm new with zend framework 2. But I'm trying my best to get along with this. I hope someone knows how to make a search like this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -3):

Firstly, fulltext indexes are only available for the InnoDB engine in MySQL 5.6.4 and above, so unless you want crippling performance when you are using anything more than a handful of rows you'd need to make sure you are using MySQL 5.6.4 or above.

With that said, I'd still recommend against using MySQL for fulltext searching. I'd recommend you look into using a search server designed for performing fulltext searches. Something like Elasticsearch, Apache Solr or Sphinx.

Comment: While I agree with what you said, it's not an answer to the question above of *how*, using Zend/Db.

Comment: @BeshoyGirgis Seriously you downvote this answer for proving useful information? There is nothing specific to ZF2 or even Zend\Db about full text search anyway. I suggest you read the help center on what constitutes an answer (Hint: It specifically says telling someone not to do something and providing an alternative as an answer) before exercising your voting privileges.